# H264 Remove Encoding Settings - Error FFMPEG

Tags: encoding, metadata, h.264

" [Removing MP4 encoding information](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18227/removing-mp4-encoding-information) " I have tried the formula of interpretation but I have compared it with such an error.

" Unknown bitstream filter h264_changesps "

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: That filter is only available in the ffmpeg version available from the link I gave there. If you've already downloaded it, make sure you are not invoking anoher ffmpeg binary found in your path.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. How to change " Writing application         : Lavf57.66.101 " Example : " Writing application         : wtfheroes "